# android remove item from listview with defined string in arrayadapter

Tags: android, string, listview, android-arrayadapter

i want to remove some items from my listview they have a string inside there i have defined.

my arrayadapter:

```
if (dayx[0] == "day1"){
       if (thisday) {
           daynotempty(rowView, textView, textView2, imageView1);
  }else{
      remove this item //here he must remove the item in array adapter
  }
```

i want to remove the item inside from my arrayadapter.I have first try it by set the rowView( `final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);`)invisible with `rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  but its always a space between the list items.but now is my question why i can delete the item from my adapter.

i hope someone can help me by my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, YOU HAVE TO USE `.equals(YOUR_STRING)` instead of `==` for Strings.

Then, to remove items, you have to recalculate your Cursor after deleting an element from database!